# Difficulty conditionally mapping many to one to duplicate output node in EDI

Tags: mapping, conditional-statements, biztalk, edi

I have a map where the data needs to map as follows:

- If RefValue2 exists, we push the value "LI" to field N901.
- If SerialValue exists, we push value "SE" to field N901.
- If either or both occur multiple times, we want a segment for each one reflecting the "LI" and "SE" values, so we need to loop over the source node to make sure we get every occurrence of these values (RefValue2 & SerialValue) so we output a correct number of segments.

I am having difficulty getting the looping/mapping right, and the build doesn't like more than one source feeding to one destination.

Comment: Please add example extracts of the input and output messages. It sounds like it shouldn't be too hard to do this.

Comment: maybe if you add just a sample input and output file, we can open visual studio and try to help you ? no ?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? Having actual code to look at and compare to your spec is how we can help you!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the looping right by playing with it. It helped to move the Looping to a separate page so it was easier to see. If I had a 10 reputation rating I could post pictures....well maybe someday. What it boiled down to was a new loop originating from the Reference2 and Serial values on the left and going to the N9_3 node on the right of the 945 file. That got me 2 instances of the N9 segment, and now I am having an alternate difficulty I will post in a minute.

Nathaniel thanks for replying to my question!